# Why are two empty string slices not acting 'equal'?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm working in Python. I have the following code:

```
while not is_suffix(pattern[:k], pattern[:q]):
    k -= 1
    print k

def is_suffix(potential_suffix, text):
    print "|" + potential_suffix + "|" + text + "|"
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if potential_suffix == text[i:]:
            return True
    return False
```

(The while loop is actually in a function, but I've omitted the non-relevant code). The result is that the while loop goes forever. The is_suffix function works when it can find two non-empty strings that are equal. However, in the case that I am having trouble with, it arrives at the end of the for loop and tries to compare text[i:] (which is empty) and potential_suffix, which is empty in this case. The code reaches the end and returns False, which causes the while loop to continue forever.

I claim that the two are empty strings because of the print line within is_suffix, which prints out "|||" in the relevant case.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing? Why would two empty strings not be considered equal?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `.endswith` method, and what `text.endswith(potential_suffix)` and `text.endswith(tuple_of_suffixes)` do?

Comment: @DSM this should be an answer, not a comment, because it is the right answer. :)

Comment: @DSM No sir, I was not familiar. I am now! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never go through the `for` loop if `text=""`.  Then, `len(text) == 0`, and `range(0) == []`, so there's nothing to loop over.  You probably want to either do an extra iteration of that loop:

```
for i in range(len(text) + 1):
```

or explicitly check for an empty suffix:

```
if suffix == "":
    return True
```

at the beginning of the function.

However, you're doing a lot of extra work in that function, since the loop is unnecessary.  The following will do what you want:

```
def is_suffix(potential_suffix, text):
    return potential_suffix == text[-len(potential_suffix):]
```

Comment: The range was exactly the problem. I was thinking it was a more fundamental lack of knowledge! Thanks. And about the extra help, I appreciate it, but there is some added functionality to go into it (requiring the extra code). I just needed to get the basics down.

Comment: The loop is honestly quite silly; there's obviously only one possible value of `i` for which a match could occur.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I think you are exiting your `is_suffix()` function with False instead of True when you think its comparing two empty strings is because of your `range(len())`

```
for i in range(len(text)):
        if potential_suffix == text[i:]:
            return True
```

If text is an empty string, then `len(text) == 0`, and `range(0) == []` so you never actually do a loop there since the list is empty.

You could change it quickly to this and see if it works:

```
if potential_suffix == text:
    return True
for i in xrange(len(text)):
        if potential_suffix == text[i:]:
            return True
```